# Custom UIActivityViewController not appear image when it is in the "More" menu item

Tags: ios

I created custom UIActivity and override variable activityImage used my image.

```
fileprivate extension UIActivity.ActivityType {
   static let extendedMessage = 
UIActivity.ActivityType("ExtendedMessage")
}
```

Custom UIActivity:

```
fileprivate class ExtendedMessageActivity: UIActivity {

private let phoneNumbers: [String]
private var message: String?
init(phoneNumbers: [String]) {
    self.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers
    super.init()
}

override static var activityCategory: UIActivity.Category {
    return .share
}
override var activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType? { return .extendedMessage }

override var activityTitle: String? { return NSLocalizedString("Message", comment: "") }

override var activityImage: UIImage? {
    return UIImage(named: "message-app-icon")
}

override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
    ....
}
override func prepare(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) {
  ....
}

override func perform() {
    ....
}

}
```

[The image appears in the set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjubE.jpg)
[I have a problem the image does not appear when it is in the "More" menu item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evNzo.jpg)
Why the image does not appear?

Answer (score 2):

Had tried to find documentation for the activity settings icon. Not found proper documentation. Just add the below code in your custom UIActivity, Working fine for me with Swift 5.2

```
@objc var _activitySettingsImage: UIImage? {
    return UIImage(named: "activitySettingsIcon")
}
```

Don't forgot to activitySettingsIcon image set in 29pt.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by adding the following (in Objective C, but you get the idea).

```
- (UIImage *)_activitySettingsImage {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-app-icon-for-setting"];
}
```

Apparently, image for more section should be smaller than the one in _activityImage. At the time of writing (XCode 12.3), 60pt for activityImage and 30pt for activitySettingsImage work for me. (I also added @2x for each image)..